# Regular expression to match numbers only not starting with zero

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a textbox on the form  and I want the user to be able to enter only numbers, and first number can not be zero. Which pattern must be in this case?

Comment: windows form or webform? for webform Aliostad got the answer for windows overload the onkeypress event an chech the key pressed for values if it's windows form i'll provide the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this expression

```
string expression = @"^[1-9]\d*$";
```

---

For anyone wanting to test the expression, use this link: http://www.rubular.com/r/1JIPP8E1zH

Comment: But it doesnt allow for eaxample 10000 number

Comment: @Namco, why?? Of course it does... Have a look here http://www.rubular.com/r/1JIPP8E1zH

Comment: oh..great  i love this site.rubular..this

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

What length of string you accept ?

If you allow empty string too try with:

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*)?$/
```

Comment: If the max length of the number is 10. then?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, and I would suggest this for localization purposes, consider

```
 double.Parse(myTextBox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

as alternative. It parses numbers with decimals or whatever variation you like according to the settings (culture) which is installed. In my country, with a dot as decimals seperator.

Comment: Nice alternative, just to note `TryParse` might be more useful, depending.