# TextField both KeyboardType.Number and KeyboardType.Decimal allows to type decimal separator

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

So I need to allow only numbers to by typed in the field.

I configured `TextField` with:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
)
```

But still it allows me to type decimal separators (comma and dot)

So I don't see any difference between `KeyboardType.Number` and `KeyboardType.Decimal`, they work exactly the same...

Number

```
@Stable
public final val Number: KeyboardType
A keyboard type used to request an IME that is capable of inputting digits. IME may provide inputs other than digits but it is not guaranteed.
```

Decimal

```
@Stable
public final val Decimal: KeyboardType
A keyboard type used to request an IME that is capable of inputting decimals. IME should explicitly provide a decimal separator as input, which is not assured by KeyboardType.Number.
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209835363):

> **Most keyboards show a decimal separator when keyboard type is set as Number**. However, it is possible that a keyboard expects `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` flag in inputType to actually show a key for decimal separator.
> This change adds a new KeyboardType called Decimal that explicitly sets the required flag. **Number and Decimal would essentially behave the same for most keyboards and OEMs**.

You can restrict the allowed characters using a regex pattern.

Something like:

```
val pattern = remember { Regex("^\\d+\$") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

Comment: ok, but I guess `text.filter { c -> c.isDigit() }` would be more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `KeyboardType.NumberPassword` to display only numbers to users which is used for entering numbers between 0 and 9 only, and very convenient for entering amounts with no decimal points. This prevents showing user comma or dash which they are not allowed to enter anyway.

Using a pattern is only required if you wish to know this is exactly an amount to prevent entries like 04, or 001. And in this case regular expression should be `^[1-9]\d*$`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5661603/5457853