# How to prevent under-posting in ASP.NET Web API OData service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have created a very simple OData v4 controller. The controller basically contains Entity Framework-backed CRUD methods for the following `Pet` entity:

```
public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

An important thing here is that `Pet.Age` is the non-nullable required property.

Here is the controller itself (only `Post` method is shown):

```
public class PetController : ODataController
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    // POST: odata/Pet
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Pet pet)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Pet.Add(pet);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Created(pet);
    }

    // Other controller methods go here...
}
```

And this is my `WebApiConfig` controller configuration:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Pet>("Pet");
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Now if I want to create a new `Pet` in my database, I issue a `POST` request like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/odata/Pet
Content-type: application/json

{ Name: "Cat", Age: 5 }
```

However, I can simply omit the `Age` property in JSON request payload, so JSON deserializer will use a default value of `0`, while I want a `400 Bad Request` status to be returned instead. This problem is called under-posting.

It can be easily solved when using regular WebApi controllers (the solution is described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)). You just create a `PetViewModel` and make your controller to accept a `PetViewModel` instead of an actual `Pet` entity:

```
public class PetViewModel
{
    // Make the property nullable and set the Required attribute
    // to distinguish between "zero" and "not set"
    [Required]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    // Other properties go here...
}
```

Then in your controller you just convert `PetViewModel` to `Pet` entity and save it to the database as usual.

Unfortunately, this approach does not work with OData controllers: if I change my `Post` method to accept `PetViewModel` instead of `Pet`, I receive the following error:

> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'PetViewModel' from content with media type 'application/json'.
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

So, is there any way to prevent under-posting when using OData controllers?

Comment: In this instance you could use a `RangeAttribute` and specify it at 1 to 999. The `ModelState.IsValid` should then catch that value 0 is not within the range and return a `BadRequest` status. The other option is to create a custom filter and manually parse the incoming JSON before it is mapped to the model but that seems like overkill.

Comment: @Igor I have solved the problem using the second approach because the generic solution to distinguish between default and `null` values was required. Have a look at the answer if you are interested. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I have solved this issue. Not sure if it is an "official" or preferred way of solving underposting problem in OData, but at least it works fine for me. So, for the lack of the official information, here is my recipe:

First, create a corresponding validation `ViewModel` for your OData entity:

```
public class PetViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Make the property nullable and set the Required attribute
    // to distinguish between "zero" and "not set"
    [Required]
    public new int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then, add your own `ODataUnderpostingValidationAttribute`. My implementation looks like this:

```
public class ODataUnderpostingValidationAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ODataUnderpostingValidationAttribute(Type viewModelType)
    {
        ViewModelType = viewModelType;
    }

    public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Rewind requestStream so it can be read again.
        var requestStream = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        if (requestStream.CanSeek)
        {
            requestStream.Position = 0;
        }

        // Read the actual JSON payload.
        var json = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Deserialize JSON to corresponding validation ViewModel.
        var viewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, ViewModelType);
        var context = new ValidationContext(viewModel);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(viewModel, context, results);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            // Throw HttpResponseException instead of setting actionContext.Response, so the exception will be logged by the ExceptionLogger.
            var responseMessage = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage)));
            throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
        }

        await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

After that, apply this custom filter to your `ODataController`:

```
[ODataUnderpostingValidation(typeof(PetViewModel))]
public class PetController : ODataController
{ /* Implementation here */ }
```

Voila! Now you have everything in place. Underposting validation works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options as I see it:

First In your controller you can check the integer value and if its below a certain value return 404.

```
if (Age <= 0)
   return NotFound();
```

This could be labor intensive and if you're doing it for every controller method it's not very DRY.

Second in your Pet class you can use the DataAnnotations Attribute Range e.g.

```
[Range(0, 80, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Where Age can be a maximum of 80.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Lastly I think your a more permanent solution for you would be to create your own validation:

```
public class AgeValidation : ValidationAttribute {
public override bool IsValid(object value) {
    if (Object.Equals(value, null)) {
        return false;
    }
    int getage;
    if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out getage)) {

        if (getage == 0)
            return false;

        if (getage > 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Then in your Pet class add:

```
[AgeValidation(ErrorMessage = "Age is wack")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Borrowed from [How to do Integer model validation in asp.net mvc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548300/how-to-do-integer-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not solve the real problem of distinguishing between _0_ and _not set_ values.

Comment: So what would be the harm in adding the [Required] attribute to the Age property? Are there cases when you want Age to be not present?

Comment: `Age` property is of type `int`, which is value type, not reference type. It will never be set to `null` after deserializing. When using `Required` attribute, a validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters. So this attribute will be useless in this scenario.

Comment: Gotcha. I just made an edit to my answer. Try adding the typeof.

Comment: I have solved the problem using a custom filter because the generic solution to distinguish between default and `null` values was required. Have a look at the answer if you are interested. Thanks for your ideas!