# asp.net core validation model: check type

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

I've the same problem discussed here: [How to do Integer model validation in asp.net mvc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548300/how-to-do-integer-model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-2) but the [Range] solution is not working with asp.net core.

Is there a way to perform a data type check during model validation?

I have this model:

```
public class Example
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Should be int!")]
    public int? SystemID { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

with this validation:

```
 public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

and if I put a string into SystemId, I obtain:

```
{
  "SystemID": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you only need to check for int, you could use regex

Comment: Or you could define [your own](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/01/03/asp-net-core-mvc/)

Comment: It doesn't work. The custom validator is bypassed in this case. It seems that the check type doesn't follow the "normal" validation.